# Count number of occurences per day, months, quarter with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

From a list of sales (colmuns A and B), how can I extract the number of sales **per day, months, quarter with Excel ?** (ie columns D, F, H)

[image]

I found some dirty code solution with

```
=SUM(DECALER(...; (LINE()-2)*31; 0; 31; 1))
```

(sorry I don't know english's translation for Excel's `DECALER` function)

but it would very annoying to have to distinguish between months of 30, 31, 28 days, etc.

**Do you know a clean solution ?**

Comment: Take a look at Pivot Tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to count for each month:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$10)=2)*(YEAR($A$1:$A$10)=2013))
```

And this for quarters:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$10)>=1)*(MONTH($A$1:$A$10)<=3)*(YEAR($A$1:$A$10)=2013))
```

I assume dates in A1:A10, the quarter example is for first quarter, for second replace 1 by 4 and 3 by 6

Answer (score 1):

Pivot Tables are the easy answer to this.

But you could inesrt 2 columns after the date

and use this forumula to get the month name

```
=TEXT(A2,"mmm")
```

In the other column use this formula to get the Quarter

```
=ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2)/3,0)
```

Then you can use COUNTIF or SUMIF depening on what you need to get your totals

Comment: Make sure you take Year into account as well so you don't count February 2013 with February 2014

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the two proposed answers given by StevenMartin and CRondao, here is what might be the simplest solution :

```
= COUNTIFS($A:$A; ">=" & C2;$A:$A; "<" & C3 )
```

This can be copied in all cells of column D and F  *(and also cells of H, provided I replace Q3, Q4 quarter names by the date of the beginning of each quarter)*.